# Small negative number maintains sign after rounding

Tags: matlab, floating-point, rounding

MATLAB seems to remember the original sign even if the rounded result is zero. The signal does not make sense anymore since the small negative value was rounded to zero.

Code sample:

```
a = - 0.001;
ar = round(a,2);
fprintf('a: %.2f. a rounded: %.2f. Zero: %.2f\n', a,ar,0);
```

result:

> a: -0.00. a rounded: -0.00. Zero: 0.00

Expected result:

> a: -0.00. a rounded: 0.00. Zero: 0.00

Comment: Just to be clear: you are asking how come the rounded value retains the negative sign, yes?

Comment: `ar = round(a,2) + 0;` behaves as expected

Comment: Very odd workaround. Strange matlab behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not specific to Matlab at all. In fact, all the programs which use IEEE754 for their floating point representation may have this particularity.

In the IEEE-754 format, there is a *sign bit*. This bit is probably left untouched during the rounding operation. So even if the result is a pure `0` in the end, the sign bit remain. This is perfectly normal behaviour for this format of floating point number:

> Main article: Signed zero
>
> In the IEEE 754 standard, zero is signed, meaning that there exist
>   both a "positive zero" (+0) and a "negative zero" (−0). In most
>   run-time environments, positive zero is usually printed as "0" and the
>   negative zero as "-0". The two values behave as equal in numerical
>   comparisons, but some operations return different results for +0 and
>   −0. For instance, 1/(−0) returns negative infinity, while 1/+0 returns
>   positive infinity (so that the identity 1/(1/±∞) = ±∞ is maintained).
>   Other common functions with a discontinuity at x=0 which might treat
>   +0 and −0 differently include log(x), signum(x), and the principal square root of y + xi for any negative number y. As with any
>   approximation scheme, operations involving "negative zero" can
>   occasionally cause confusion. For example, in IEEE 754, x = y does not
>   always imply 1/x = 1/y, as 0 = −0 but 1/0 ≠ 1/−0.

<sub>Source: [Wikipedia Floating_point Signed_zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Signed_zero)</sub>

---

Now Matlab display a sign in front of the zero because you asked to display it in a floating point format (`%.2f`), so Matlab respect the norm and display the sign.

If you let Matlab choose the best way to display, Matlab will be smart and drop the zero:

```
>> disp(ar)
     0
```

Also, Matlab knows that the value is `0` and will return the right value if you query the sign of the value:

```
>> sign(ar)
ans =
     0
```

*Matlab would return `-1` if it was considered negative and `+1` if it was considered positive.* So despite the respect of the IEEE-754 norm at display time, Matlab is not confused and knows that this value has no meaningful sign.

In conclusion, do not worry about it. It is not going to bring any programmatic problem or calculation issue.

If your only grief is the display, another workaround could be simply to multiply the absolute value by the `sign` detected by Matlab (since it detects the right sign).
You can make a custom rounding function which could take care of that if really important:

```
mround = @(x,n) abs(round(x,n))*sign(round(x,n)) ;
arm = mround(a,2) ;
fprintf('a: %.2f. a rounded: %.2f. Zero: %.2f\n', a,arm,0);

a: -0.00. a rounded: 0.00. Zero: 0.00
```

Granted here the rounding operation is evaluated twice because I used that in an inline function, but if you put that in a function with multiple lines, you evaluate the rounding only once then correct the sign with the same method.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the post by Bob Gilmore (from The MathWorks) on the MATLAB forums](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/251089), MATLAB respects the sign bit when performing various operations as specified by the ANSI/IEEE floating-point standard.

> As per [section 6.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Zero) of [ANSI/IEEE Std. 754-1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), MATLAB honors the sign bit "even when operands or results are zero or infinite."

As such, when using `round`, even though all of the exponent and fraction bits are set to 0, the [*sign bit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit) remains the same as the input (in your case this is `1` indicating a negative number). `fprintf` *also* respects this sign bit when displaying your value and therefore adds the explicit negative sign.

You can also get the same behavior by explicitly specifying that you want `-0`:

```
fprintf('%0.2f\n', -0);
%// -0.00
```

This is also observable with other things such as a division by 0:

```
1/0   %// Inf

1/-0  %// -Inf
```

We can also observe this by changing the display format to `hex`:

```
format hex

disp(0)

    0000000000000000

disp(-0)

    8000000000000000
```

Note the different in the first entry indicative of the difference in the sign bit.

[As @zeeMonkeez noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1893154/zeemonkeez), a simple workaround is to add `0` to your result which in the case of a -0, seems to flip the sign bit:

```
fprintf('%0.2f\n', -0 + 0);
%// 0.00
```